# Indirect narration

Tags: reported-speech

What is the indirect narration of " he said,'Good morning John.'" Whether it is "he wished john good morning" or "he greeted john good morning." Which one is correct.?

Comment: You can't use _greet_ to introduce indirect speech like that, so it has to be _wished_. (NB _John_ always needs a capital letter.)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't necessarily just one way to make speech indirect.

The most obvious way to me is:

> He wished John a good morning.

Without the article I would be inclined to consider it direct speech and would punctuate it like this:

> He wished John, "Good morning."